# Counting distinct first child value element of each parent in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Using a XSLT stylesheet, I am trying to count the distinct values for each first child node of the parent element.

Example XML:

```
<Root>
<Parent>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value2</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value3</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
</Parent>
 <Parent>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value2</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value2</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
</Parent>
 <Parent>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value2</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
    <Child>
            <Child2>
              <Child3>Value2</Child3>
            </Child2>
    </Child>
</Parent>
</Root>
```

Using my above XML example, the expected result would be 1.
I have managed to count the distinct values for all the children by using the count function, but I can't figure out how to do it for each first child.

```
count(//Parent/Child/Child2/Child3[not(.=following::Child3)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Parent/Child[1]/Child2/Child3[not(.=following::Parent/Child[1]/Child2/Child3)])" />
```

Which is not very elegant, or efficient.

But you have tagged this as XSLT 1.0, which suggests you are performing the count inside a stylesheet. If so, consider defining a key like so:

```
 <xsl:key name="children" match="Parent/Child[1]/Child2" use="Child3" />
```

Then the expression becomes this....

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(//Child2[generate-id() = generate-id(key('children', Child3)[1])])" />
```

This makes use of a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which is worth reading up for.